# IBM IoT for Automotive: What does value '-1000' returned from some Vehicle APIs as 'heading', 'altitude', etc.?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, iot-for-automotive

Why does the value `-1000` get returned from some Vehicle APIs as  `heading`, `altitude`, etc.?

For example:

The following parameters/values are returned after sending `get event information (/event)` from the REST API.

The value of `altitude` and 'heading' is `-1000`.  What does `-1000` mean?

```
   {"contents":[{"event_time":.....,"e_altitude":-1000.0,.....,"heading":-1000.0,...}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those values mean that `null` is actually set to the field rather than `-1000`.

IoT for Automotive will update the APIs so that its behavior becomes more clear in the future release, like setting `null` to those fields in the response.